# HOME activity will not show up or act as home activity

Tags: android, homescreen

This is my first time asking a question on on here, but I have found the answer to innumerable questions I've had before on here. However, I just can't make this one work. I'm simply trying to write an app to replace the homescreen. Here is what I am trying, and I can't see what I'm missing.

To keep it as simple as possible, I reduced it to just this testing application. The only thing I changed after starting a new project was the manifest.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.hometesting"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="17"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".HomeActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:stateNotNeeded="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME"/>                
                <category android:name="android.intent.categoty.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I have tried it both in the emulator and my own phone, in the latter, it doesn't show up in the chooser. I can select it as the default home application in the user settings, but when i hit the home button, it just brings up the chooser without my app as an option. The pre-installed home screens and one other app that I downloaded show up as options, but my app doesn't. In the emulator, a click on the home button just brings up the default homescreen.

I have tried it with and without the separate launcher activity, and with and without the LAUNCHER intent. I have tried installing, uninstalling, restarting, and every permutation thereof.

All I want is for the home button to lead back to an activity that I wrote. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Update: I also tried it on a generic cheap Chinese device, and still nothing.

Comment: have you analysed what other working home-screen apps use as intent-filter? you can do this with [intent-intercept](https://github.com/intrications/intent-intercept) that available on [google play store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=uk.co.ashtonbrsc.android.intentintercept)

Comment: I just downloaded it and tried it, it doesn't seem to intercept the home button intent

Comment: if you find out how to intercept "HOME activity" please let us know how you did it so that intet-intercept can be updated accordingly

Comment: Will do, though I expect it will be the answer I'm looking for.

Comment: use this tutorial http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/build-a-custom-launcher-on-android--cms-21358 and here http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2583692

Comment: I had found both of those tutorials when I was searching for an answer before I posted this question. I looked at them again, and as far as I can tell, what I have is exactly what they are saying to do. I must be missing something simple, but I can't see what it is.